# Python Google Calendar API v3 does not return the "summary" field when listing event items

Tags: python, python-2.7, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a python script that is going to run a cron operation. 
It needs to find a list of events for the current day, and then perform some other action depending on the event. 
So far, I am able to make a request to the Calendar API, and I am getting a list of events for the current day.
When I loop through the list of event items, the "summary" key for the item is missing. 
I need this field so that I can determine what the event is for.

The data in each event item is coming back like this with no "summary" key

```
{
  "status": "confirmed",
  "kind": "calendar#event",
  "end": {
    "date": "2017-07-29"
  },
  "iCalUID": "0000000000000@google.com",
  "updated": "2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z",
  "start": {
    "date": "2017-07-24"
  },
  "etag": "\"0000000000000000\"",
  "id": "0000000000000"
}
```

In the Google docs found here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource it shows the "summary" key should be returned with the event.

Since this script is going to run automatically, I setup a Google Service account to authorize the request to the API so that a user doesn't have to authorize it manually. Here is a sample of the script that I'm using

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build
import datetime

try:
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        '/path/to/credentials/filename.json', scopes=scopes)

    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

    startTime = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + 'T00:00:00-07:00'
    endTime = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + 'T23:59:00-07:00'
    calendar = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http_auth)
    calId = 'calendar_id_string'

    response = calendar.events().list(calendarId=calId, 
    timeMin=startTime, timeMax=endTime).execute()

    items = response.get('items',[])
    for item in items:
        summary = item.get('summary','') # summary is blank!!

except Exception, ex:
    print ex
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the event "summary" was not returned to the client is because of a calendar permission that was set for an email account.

The email account came from the credentials JSON file that was created when I made the Service Account.

When the calendar was shared with the email account, the permission was set to "See only free/busy (hide details)" instead of "See all event details" by the admin.

With the "See only free/busy (hide details)" permission, a user can only see if the calendar is free or busy at a given time, but no event details are returned.

By changing this permission to "See all event details" then all of the event details will be returned back to the client, including the "summary" key which is what I need.

See here for more details:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts

Only the Calendar Owner can change the permissions on a calendar. If you are the owner then,

- Log into Google Calendar
- Click on the Settings Gear button
- Click Settings > Calendars > [Your Calendar Name] > Share this Calendar
- Find the email account and change the permission setting
- Click Save

Otherwise, you will need to contact the owner about changing the permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a G suite account, and have your own domain name, then the administrator of the domain must authorize the client following these instructions here.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority

Note - In order to authorize the client, you must have already created a service account with the "Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation" checked.  Then give the client_id to the administrator along with the scope, so it can be authorized by the administrator.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

After the Service account was enabled with the "G Suite Domain-wide Delegation," and the client and scope was authorized by the domain administrator, then you should be able to see all of the event details after making the api call. Here is an example below. Hope this helps others

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build
import datetime

try:
    # updated the scopes with "calendar.readonly"
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        '/path/to/credentials/filename.json', scopes=scopes)

    # create a credential object with an authorized user with read access to the calendar
    delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('authorized_user_email@your_domain.com')
    http_auth = delegated_credentials.authorize(Http())

    startTime = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + 'T00:00:00-07:00'
    endTime = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + 'T23:59:00-07:00'
    calendar = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http_auth)
    calId = 'calendar_id_string'

    response = calendar.events().list(calendarId=calId, timeMin=startTime, timeMax=endTime).execute()

    items = response.get('items',[])
    for item in items:
        summary = item.get('summary','') # Event summary exists!! Yea!!

except Exception, ex:
    print ex
```