# Google calendar api orderBy="startTime" work wrong (python)

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have this schedule:
[image]

I'm just running the example on the site https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python?

I get this result:
Getting the upcoming 10 events

2024-03-26T11:45:00+03:00 Event for check time

2024-03-26T14:00:00+03:00 Event for test

2024-04-20T12:00:00+03:00 Повторяющееся событие

2024-05-18T12:00:00+03:00 Повторяющееся событие

2024-06-15T12:00:00+03:00 Повторяющееся событие

2024-07-20T12:00:00+03:00 Повторяющееся событие

2024-08-17T12:00:00+03:00 Повторяющееся событие

2024-09-21T12:00:00+03:00 Повторяющееся событие

2024-10-19T12:00:00+03:00 Повторяющееся событие

2024-11-16T12:00:00+03:00 Повторяющееся событие

For the first two events I see the correct dates and start times.
But the following dates are wrong. This can be seen in the picture.
The third event is about to start 2024-03-27
It turns out that sorting for repeating events is not working correctly

I've run the example several times

Comment: Why the event names are different on the screenshot vs what you get from API? Could you be looking at events from a different calendar in UI?

Comment: Yes, the names are different. As far as I understand, you need a service account in order to receive the correct names. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379450/python-google-calendar-api-v3-does-not-return-the-summary-field-when-listing-e